# My A-Frame scene renders behind the camera when I wear a VR headset

Tags: aframe

I pasted the code from A-Frame's [hello world sample scene](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe#example), directly from their GitHub homepage, into [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/sensei/full/ZEEOEQO).

The scene looks fine when I view it on desktop, and even when I view it on my phone.  But when I view it on my phone AND click the VR headset button (at lower right), the entire scene renders behind me!  (As if the z-axis were suddenly flipped!)

[Here is a CodePen](https://codepen.io/sensei/full/xxxOxJj) with an even simpler example:

```
<a-scene>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="green"></a-sphere>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 5" radius="1.25" color="red"></a-sphere>
</a-scene>
```

That is, a green sphere 5 units in front of the camera, and a red sphere 5 units behind the camera.  When viewed from my desktop or my phone (a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge, which is VR capable) in regular mode I see the green sphere, but when I view the scene from my phone in VR mode, I see the red sphere (and have to turn around, looking behind me) to see the green sphere.

What's going on?  Do you see the same thing?  And how do I solve this problem?!?

Comment: is the gyroscope rotating the scene before you press 'enter VR' ?

Comment: I had the same issue with Oculus Go. I remember that I spent a lot of time to find a solution and actually found it but unfortunately it worked not always. The solution was to set camera position pragmatically. You need to create a group (a.k.a camera holder) put this camera into this element and move this element (not camera itself) on required distance. Should help.

Comment: I've understood that the camera is rotating after entering VR rather than changing position

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski correct!  The camera is rotating after entering VR - it's not changing position; and the gyroscope is not rotating the scene before I enter VR mode.  Note that with my phone (S7 Edge) it seems like the scene rotates a full 180º, but on my wife's phone (iPhone SE) it seems like the scene rotates ~90º; that is, she sees the green sphere at first, but then (after going into VR mode) she sees the red sphere but NOT directly in front of her (as I did), but rather slightly off camera to the right.

Comment: @SenseiJames are you sure it's not adjusting the rotation to the gyroscope readings ? Is it always 180deg (S7) and 90deg (iPSE) ?

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski you are exactly right!  It is adjusting to the gyroscope readings (just tried by holding my phone in different positions) - if I turn my phone over (holding it in landscape mode, but with the top to the left instead of to the right) I get the desired effect; it's only when I was holding it in landscape mode (with top to the right) that the scene was rotating 180º.

Comment: @RomanMahotskyi your suggestion is the solution!  Feel free to post your code, else I'll do so once I've some daylight.

Comment: @SenseiJames I don't have A-Frame example. I worked with Three.js directly (which A-Frame uses under the hood). Feel free to share your code example with others.

Answer (score 0):

The root problem (as @PiotrAdamMilewski suggested) is that my phone was taking on the gyroscope's orientation upon entering VR mode.  The solution is to aim the camera at the scene when the user puts on their VR headset - this ensures that the user will be looking exactly where you want when their VR experience begins.

HTML (Angular 8):

```
<a-scene #scene>
 <!-- ... -->

  <a-entity #cameraParent>
    <a-entity camera look-controls pointerLockEnabled #camera>
    </a-entity>
  </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

JavaScript (TypeScript):

```
  @ViewChild('scene', { static : true }) scene;
  @ViewChild('cameraParent', { static : true }) cameraParent;
  @ViewChild('camera', { static : true }) camera;

  // ...

  this.scene.nativeElement.addEventListener('enter-vr', ()=> {
    const camera = this.camera.nativeElement;
    const cameraParent = this.cameraParent.nativeElement;
    cameraParent.object3D.rotation.x = -camera.object3D.rotation.x;
    cameraParent.object3D.rotation.y = -camera.object3D.rotation.y;
    cameraParent.object3D.rotation.z = -camera.object3D.rotation.z;
  });
```

Notice the camera is wrapped in a container, and that we rotate the camera's container (by the reverse of the camera angle) rather than the camera itself.  Props to @PiotrAdamMilewski for helping me identify the root cause, and to @RomanMahotskyi for suggesting this implementation.  Teamwork makes the dream work!